Union of sets under linear surjective transformation
I have been given the set:
$$X=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k$$
Where $B_k$ are open balls of radius $k$ (but that doesn't matter). Also the transformation $T:X\rightarrow Y$ which is linear and surjective. Now The textbook says that due to these properties we have:
$$Y=T(X)=T\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k \right)=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}T(B_k) $$
It's obvious that the surjectivity comes in handy in the first equal sign  so the third must be due to the linearity. I can't understand why does the linearity give us this property. Also why doesn't that hold for any transformation $T$? I can't think of a counter example.

Open balls where?

Note that
\begin{align} y \in T\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k \right)  &\iff \exists x,\ x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k,\ Tx=y \\
&\iff \exists x \exists k,\ x \in B_k,\ Tx = y \\
&\iff \exists k \exists x,\ x \in B_k,\ Tx = y \\
&\iff \exists k\, y \in T(B_k) \\
&\iff y \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty T(B_k)
\end{align}
so linearity is not required. It must be used somewhere else in the discussion.

I guess the linearity comes in play somewhere else, yes

We know for finite unions, it always holds, i.e. in general settings of sets and maps, we have for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $$T(\bigcup_{1\leq k \leq n} B_k) = \bigcup_{1\leq k \leq n} T( B_k). $$
With this, it is clear that$T(\bigcup_{1\leq k \leq n} B_k)  \subset  \bigcup_{k= 1}^{\infty} T( B_k) $. Hence, by linearity and since $\{\bigcup_{1\leq k\leq n} B_k\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically increasing (limit goes inside by MCT!), $T(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k)\subset \bigcup_{k= 1}^{\infty} T( B_k) $. On the other hand, $\bigcup_{1\leq k \leq n} T( B_k) \subset T(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k) $. Take limits as $n\to \infty$ and get $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} T( B_k) \subset T(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k) $. Now, by surjectivity, since the open balls $B_k$ cover your domain top space, the image $T(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k) = Y$. That is, as you said, $Y = T(X) = T(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k)=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} T(B_k)$.
